# Difference between .find() and 'in' operator in python

Tags: python, pandas, find, in-operator

I'm working on Dataframe with pandas called *filteredDS*

***The aim:***

> Searching for all data, whose *question* column contains *'King'* word.

When I add the column *king_quest* via *in* operator like this:

```
filteredDS['king_quest'] = filteredDS.question.apply(lambda x: x if ' King ' in x else None).reset_index(drop = True)
filtered_king_df = filteredDS[~filteredDS.king_quest.isnull()].reset_index()
print(filtered_king_df)
```

I get dataframe with about 2000 rows,
And when I add it via .find() function like this:

```
filteredDS['king_quest'] = filteredDS.question.apply(lambda x: x if x.find('king') else None).reset_index(drop = True)
filtered_king_df = filteredDS[~filteredDS.king_quest.isnull()].reset_index()
print(filtered_king_df)
```

I get dataframe with about 3000 rows.

**Note:** in both cases, each row in *question* column has the *'king'* word.

Could you tell why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be multiple issues here.

1. Your find is looking for different values in the statements. ' King ' (spaces, initial letter cap in one) and just 'king' in the other.
2. x.find('king') returns the index of the first matching and -1 otherwise. If you want to use this to check, you should probably check `x.find('king') > 0`, but that is not as intuitive as `'king' in x`

Comment: Yeah, you're right
I wrote `lambda x: x if x.find('king')!=-1 else None`
Then it gave exactly the same result as the *'in'* operator gave.
Thank you)

Answer (score 1):

**in operator**

The ‘in’ operator is used to check if a value exists in a sequence or not. Evaluates to true if it finds a variable in the specified sequence and false otherwise.

```
# Python program to illustrate 
# Finding common member in list  
# using 'in' operator 
list1=[1,2,3,4,5] 
list2=[6,7,8,9] 
for item in list1: 
    if item in list2: 
        print("found")       
else: 
    print("not found")
```

**find() method**
The find() method returns the lowest index of the substring if it is found in given string. If its is not found then it returns -1.

```
word = 'the tea looks good, this tea is for me;Thank you'

# returns first occurrence of Substring
result = word.find('tea')
print("Substring 'tea' found at index:", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more comprehensive explanation of the find() method:

- It looks for a substring and returns the index of first occurrence of the substring
- It doesn't generate an error for an argument containing an non-existent substring - in case of a non-existent substring, it returns -1
- It works with strings only

It has a two-parameter variant, find( string, position) where string is your string and position specifies the index at which the search will be started. if you don't specify a position, the find() will start at the beginning of the string.

It also has a three-parameter variate, the first two parameter are like in the two-parameter variant, and the third parameter is the position at which first index won't be taken into consideration during the search. You can think of it of having this signature: find(string, starting_position, ending_position) and the ending_position is not included

I haven't used filteredDS before and I'm not familiar with it, and I hope this example below can help you think of a way to apply the find() method to your case. This code prints the indices of all occurrences of the word "it" in the string "text".

text = " Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software. It is widely used."

```
index = text.find("it")
while index != -1:
    print(index)
    index = text.find("it", index+1)
```